# Copying Jpegs in Python

Tags: python, import, operating-system, shutil

Hello there I am new programmer trying to write a program to copy all jpegs found on my computer over to a folder.

The program seems to be working in the sense that it finds all the jpegs but when it comes to copying them over to the new folder nothing happens.

Can someone please help me? Thanks

Ive made sure that the permissions on the destination folder are good to go.

```
# program to go through all directories
# and copy found jpg files
# to new folder
import os
from shutil import copy2

#replace below with your directory / destination folder
src = "/home/coyotejoe"
dst = '/home/coyotejoe/Desktop/JPG'



for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src, topdown=True):
   for name in files:

         if name.endswith('jpg'):

            try:
               copy2(os.path.join(src,name), os.path.join(dst, name))

            except:
               pass
```

prints the names of all jpegs but destination folder is still blank

Comment: Disable the `try/except` block to see if it raises an exception. Also isn't this going to find the already copied files too as `dst` is a subdirectory of `src`?

Comment: alright so the exception is                                                                             Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/coyotejoe/3490_13.jpg'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/coyotejoe/3490_09.jpg'
......................................... on and on and on, how would I assign a destination folder that wouldnt be a subdirectory of src?   thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my computer on a directory which has 'png' files and it works.

```
#replace below with your directory / destination folder
src = "C:\S\SODTEST\SODTEST"
dst = 'C:\S\SODTEST'

import os
from shutil import copy2

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src, topdown=True):
   for name in files:
         if name.endswith('png'):
            try:
               copy2(os.path.join(src,name), os.path.join(dst, name))

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Observe the exception you are getting instead of makine it fail silently.

You are os-walking and ignoring subdirectories. If you have subdirectories with jpgs in them) use `copy2(os.path.join(root, name), os.path.join(dst, name))`.

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your help, I ran your code and I get this error
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/coyotejoe/3490_01.jpg'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/coyotejoe/3490_0.jpg'                                     ....... on and on and on, I think thats why its not copying them over, maybe I am confused about the src and dst variables? I just want to copy all jpegs on computer to new folder, any ideas? Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: Are you sure that all of your JPG files immediately under `/home/coyotejoe`. You are os-walking and ignoring subdirectories.

Comment: Use `root` for src path join not `src` if you have subdirectories with JPG files in them. The error is probably because 3490_01.jpg is in one of the subdirectories of  `home/coyotejoe`.

Comment: using root in the the src path join worked! thanks so much Siddik!

Comment: I would appreciate if you could accept the answer if it helps you.